# NextJS server-side rendering not disabled on dynamic import

Tags: next.js

I'm not able to get dynamic import to work, [image]

```
//event.js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const NoSsrLiveStreaming = dynamic(
  () => import("@/components/ui/LiveStreaming"),
  {
    ssr: false
  }
);

async function Event() {
  return (
    <>
      <div suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
        <NoSsrLiveStreaming />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Event;
```

component:

```
     //LiveStreaming.js
function LiveStreaming() {
  const [appid, setAppid] = useState("");
  const [token, setToken] = useState("");
  const [channel, setChannel] = useState("");

  let client, agoraObj;

  if (isBrowser) {
    client = AgoraRTC.createClient({ codec: "h264", mode: "rtc" });
    agoraObj = isBrowser() ? useAgora(client) : {};
  }

  const {
    localAudioTrack,
    localVideoTrack,
    leave,
    join,
    joinState,
    remoteUsers
  } = isBrowser
    ? agoraObj
    : {
        localAudioTrack: null,
        localVideoTrack: null,
        leave: null,
        join: null,
        joinState: null,
        remoteUsers: null
      };
```

It seems like it's loading the hook `useLiveStream` even though I disabled SSR with dynamic import.
I do have a hook in this component `useAgora(client)`, and this hook has window objects that threw errors. That's the reason why I wrapped this around an `if` browser check statement.
How do i get around this?

[image: livestreaming component]

Comment: When you dynamically import a component with `ssr: false` it will only get loaded on the client. Also note that you should not conditionally call hooks, you're breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Comment: @juliomalves how do you completely disable SSR for specific pages? dynamic imports don't work bc there's a window variable in the SDK, and it will be read regardless of being loaded on client side or not. It produced an error for me even though I used dynamic import, due to the window var

Comment: Dynamically loading the component should work in that case. Can you please show the error you're seeing?

Comment: @juliomalves I attached a screenshot above.

Comment: Is `LiveStreaming` not a React component? What does it return? Can you show the full code for it?

Comment: it is a react component. I just added the screenshot of the code

Comment: Please add the code as a snippet, do not use images for code.

Comment: The dynamic import and the imported component are fine. The issue is with your `Event` component, you can't have a React function component be `async`. Replace `async function Event()` with `function Event()`.

Comment: @juliomalves can I rewrite this as `const Event = () => {}` xxx?

Comment: OMG, that solved my problem! Please create a solution so I could vote for it. This is so crucial for my bug! thanks so much

Comment: Yes, you can also use `const Event = () => {}` syntax.